# Restore Firefox & Thunderbird user data from Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, migration, firefox

I have a fresh installation to which I want to transfer my Firefox and Thunderbird user data. I have my Time Machine backup available from Other backup disk and could in principle restore the hidden Library folder. However, I don't want to migrate everything from my old Library to the fresh install.

Which Firefox and Thunderbird user data folders do I have to migrate to my fresh installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The User Data folders for Firefox and Thunderbird are:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Firefox
/Users/$USER/Library/Thunderbird
```

You might also want to migrate the *.plist* files for them as well:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist
/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.thunderbird.plist
```

Make sure the applications are close before migrating the folders/files.